# Remove multiple sprites from stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I've created a list of sprites (to hold textfields), how would I remove all the created sprites?

creating the sprites:

```
    for (var i:int = 0; i < optionsArray[currentChoicePart].length; i++) 
    {
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',15,0xFFFFFF);
        txt.text = optionsArray[currentChoicePart][i];
        txt.filters = [stroke];
        txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        txt.selectable = false;
        txt.width = 400
        txt.height = 25
        var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
        btn.mouseChildren = false;
        btn.addChild(txt); 
        btn.buttonMode = true;
        btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 10
        btn.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 50 * (i * .5)
        btn.name = "p" + String((Number(currentPart.substring(1)) + (i+1)))
        stage.addChild(btn)
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function m(zen:MouseEvent) // when button is clicked 
        {
            choice(zen.currentTarget.name)

        } 
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire approach is all wrong and your code the way it is written is only producing more headaches for you than it really should. You only need a special way to remove those buttons because you create that situation for yourself. In reality a more simple and more efficient code would be to have your button set in a specific sprite and then simply remove all buttons from that sprite like:

```
var buttonHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
stage.addChild(buttonHolder);

//for loop
for (var i:int = 0; i < optionsArray[currentChoicePart].length; i++) 
//etc ... 
buttonHolder.addChild(btn);
//here the button is added to his specific holder
```

No removing button becomes very easy

```
buttonHolder.removeChildren();
```

Adding everything to the stage directly is a clue of inexperience for a coder. Nothing really should ever be added to the stage. Instead from your document class you should add more layers (Sprite) and add to those layers depending on your needs. You end up with a very easy to manage display list and set of layers. Adding to the stage will always make your work and logic more difficult and full of headaches down the road.

EDIT:

Looping through a display list or an array in order to remove or add from it is not recommended because it's tricky and can easily produce error. If you add or remove then the number of element changes and the loop which relies on that number might end up with weird results. If you remove then the loop will terminate too soon missing some element to remove. Instead typically this is done with a while loop to avoid this problem.

```
while(buttonHolder.numChildren)
{
    buttonHolder.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

Also the removeChildren method must be called like this

```
removeChildren();
```

not like this:

```
removeChildren;//missing ()
```

Comment: It works, but it only removes 2/3 of the children.    for (var i2:int = 0; i2 < bh.numChildren; i2++)
   {
    bh.removeChildAt(i2)
   }
tracing the number of children outputs 3, although it only removes 2

Comment: I gave you the removeChildren() method example, why don't you want to use that one? You can't loop through display list using numChildren to remove children since each time you remove one the numChildren value changes, that's why this is done using while loop instead as in while(numChildren){removeChildAt(0)}

Comment: Remove children isn't a thing though? It just gives me a undefined method error or something like that

Comment: set FP version to 11 not 10. If you don't want to then use the while loop as I shown: while(bn.numChildren){bn.removeChildAt(0)}

Comment: Doing what you said, it's on version 11 but it gives me this error: Property removeChildren not found on flash.display.Sprite and there is no default value

Comment: show the code you wrote, it shouldn't even say 'property'

Comment: the removeChildren method starts at FP 11. The error talks about "property" which is not normal if you make a normal function call with "()" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshel, I would recommend to save links to the buttons somewhere (e.g. Vector.) and just go through the list when you need to remove all buttons.

Try this code (please, pay attention to the comments):

import flash.display.Sprite;

var btns:Vector. = new Vector.();

```
function init():void
{
    trace("init");

    for (var i:int = 0; i < optionsArray[currentChoicePart].length; i++) 
    {
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',15,0xFFFFFF);
        txt.text = optionsArray[currentChoicePart][i];
        txt.filters = [stroke];
        txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        txt.selectable = false;
        txt.width = 400
        txt.height = 25
        var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
        btn.mouseChildren = false;
        btn.addChild(txt); 
        btn.buttonMode = true;
        btn.x = stage.stageWidth / 10
        btn.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 50 * (i * .5)
        btn.name = "p" + String((Number(currentPart.substring(1)) + (i+1)))
        stage.addChild(btn)
        btn.addEventListener(
            MouseEvent.CLICK, 
            function m(zen:MouseEvent) // when button is clicked 
            {
                choice(zen.currentTarget.name);
            } 
        )

        // Each button is put in the list,
        // to be able to work with the button after
        btns.push(btn);
    }

    trace(btns.length);
}

function reset():void
{
    trace("reset");

    var tempBtn:Sprite;
    var btnsCount:int = btns.length;
    // We just go through the list and remove all buttons from theirs parents
    for(var btnIndex:int = 0; btnIndex < btnsCount; btnIndex++)
    {
        tempBtn = btns[btnIndex];
        tempBtn.parent.removeChild(tempBtn);
    }

    btns = new Vector.<Sprite>();
}

init();
setTimeout(reset, 3000);
```

Also, I've tested the code above with commented lines where I don't have variables such as optionsArray, stroke, e.t.c.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Main/createOptions()[C:\Users\badfitz66\Documents\Projects\Text adventure\src\Main.as:142]
 at Main/onEnter()[C:\Users\badfitz66\Documents\Projects\Text adventure\src\Main.as:92]

Comment: @Badfitz66 It looks like you have huge code. It would be great if you show the other part of your code the check where the problem is.

Comment: line 157 is just this line: btns.push(btn), all my code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/XJP9dGL1

Comment: fixed it. I defined the btns array as btns:Array and not btns:Array = new Array();. My problem still persists though, how would I remove all of the created buttons